# Single Word Request: List of town tasks

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or small phrase for "a list of tasks that a town or village has set out to accomplish, specifically for the improvement of the community"

The best I have so far is "agenda" but it's not quite what I'm going for.

If it makes any difference / influences your word choices, this word/phrase is to be the title of the list of achievements in a town-builder game.

Comment: not 'accomplishments'?

Comment: Having been a *Parish Councillor* and having a wife who is a *Parish Clerk* (England), I cab assure you that there is a *huge* number of such tasks, including routine maintenance of public areas and buildings, parking, litter, traffic, development, planning & development; annual fairs; public events; etc. etc.. Many are permanently ongoing and hence can never be considered as 'complete' or 'accomplished'.

Comment: @TrevorD: Those might be better described as _responsibilities_.

Comment: @TrevorD, this will be in a game where there will be a concept of 100% accomplishment.

Comment: In Australia, if these tasks are not performed by a council directly, they may be organised by a "Progress Association", but a quick Google search didn't find a one word term for their initiatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might consider **[milestones](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/milestone)**

> An important event, as in a person's career, the history of a nation, or the advancement of knowledge in a field; a turning point

To convey the *town* aspect, you may want to try **municipal milestones**

Comment: This could work. *nods*. Although I like the alliteration of municipal milestones, I might have to settle with "Town Milestones" with my target audience.

Comment: There is a short form of *municipal* that is sometimes used - **muni**. Maybe **Muni-Milestones** (the term *muni* is also used to refer to municipal bonds)

Comment: At least as a working title, this is the one we've gone for.

Comment: +1 @JamesWebster Then you've met the first milestone, I imagine.

Comment: Just as a comment I've never heard muni used as an abbreviation for Municipal so would advise shying away from that. I suspect it is a regional abbreviation of some kind (UK english speaker here).

Answer (score 7):

1- Attainments

2- Achievments

3- To-Do list

4- Task list

5- Horizon

6-Accomplishments

Answer (score 0):

In General, activities associated with town or city management are described as being *Civic*, from Latin [civicus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/civic) (“pertaining to a city or citizens”).

As such, if your list of achievements is the desired day-to-day operations of the town or city, it could be called the *Civic Charter*. 
If the list is in the context of a short term, finite project, this could be called a *Civic Plan*, *Civic Program*, or *Civic Project*. 
If the list only expresses achievements in the past tense, it could be called a list of *Civic Achievements* or *Accomplishments*, or as commented earlier, *Civic Milestones*.

Another word with similar meaning is *Municipal*.