# A phrase for "Actions to do"

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to list some actions that needs to be done and can't find a good phrase for it.

I want to write something like:

> Now we're creating appropriate elements.
>   Operational summary:
>   1. doing X
>   2. Having Y
>   3. Writing Z

What would you suggest instead of "Operational summary"?

---

**Edit #1 (30 Sep, 22:30):**
I should clarify that I have a list of actions that my code does and I want to summarize them by their order.

Comment: Also see  [“What needs to be done” vs “What is needed to be done”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/18799),   [Single Word Request: List of town tasks](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/125083),   [“List of tasks” or “tasks’ list”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/43020),  and  [“Todo list” or “to-do list”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/46217)

Comment: @jwpat7: None seemed suitable.

Comment: _Agenda_: Latin 'those things that are to be done'. (This is an example, btw, of the ***Gerundive*** form of the verb _ago, agere_ 'to do'; not to be confused with the _Gerund_ form, a different participle altogether. Latin had a lot of nonfinite verb forms.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From computer science:

- Procedure
- Algorithm

Comment: Procedure is good! It's not what I had in mind but I like it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about **action points** or [**action items**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_item)? It's common terminology in business.

Comment: I'm not sure if it fits.. In general I have a list of actions that my code does and I want to summarize them by their order.

Comment: You didn't mention code before. You may want to clarify the scope and context of your question, perhaps.

Comment: At first I didn't understand the importance of this.

Answer (score 0):

> How about

- Our plan of attack:
- Our mission in ranked order of priorities:
- Our modus operandi in three steps/stages:
- Our methodology:
- Our to-do list in chronological order:
- Our agenda:
- Our operational strategy:
- The method to our madness:
- An overview of the tasks before us:
- A summary of our protocol:

Am I on the right track?  Surely, one of the above must be spot on, or close to it!

Comment: Sorry.. but the phrases are too "big" to use them (like "plan of attack" or "agenda"). I just have a list of small steps that would be done by the order that is shown, and that list represents a code. The rest of the phrases doesn't seem to fit... don't know, maybe I'm the one who got it wrong? I can almost "feel" that there's a very good phrase for this but I can't remember..